# Progress Error:Connect to database in $DLC (1379)

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

How to connect database in $DLC in progress openedge. for details see below image.
 [image]

Thanks,
Purushottam

Answer (score 1):

Databases in $DLC (the directory that Progress was installed in) are templates -- you must make a copy of the template db in some other directory in order to use it.  You cannot run databases directly from $DLC.

Usually you use a command such as:

```
proenv> prodb sports sports
```

To make a local copy of the default "sports" db.

Or you can just type "prodb" and you will be prompted for the new db name and the template name.  The new name can be different from the template name.

Comment: Thanks Tom , 

Can you please tell me progress (openedge) Query .How to display all data from Table in Sports database.

Comment: That sounds like a new question.  You should accept this answer and open a new topic for that.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to create a copy of sports database in other directory (not in openedge installation directory) using procopy or prodb command.
For Ex : in proenv
         **procopy Sports2000 D:\spdb** Or,
         **prodb D:\spdb Sports2000**.
Now, you can easily connect to the database...

Comment: Hi Tom,
     How to resolve "system text record not on file.(138)" error message in progress.